# Windows 7 detects 32 Gb, but can allocate only 16 gb (Update: MySql)

Tags: windows-7, memory, 64-bit, mysql

I have:

1) Gygabyte 990FXA UD3 rev 1.2
2) 4 x 8 GB (Kingston 9905403-518.A00LF)
3) AMD FX-8320

Windows detects 32 GB, BIOS also detects 32 GB.
But when OS loaded it does not allow to use more than approximately 13Gb (even not 16 gb).
I tried different software... For example Sysinternals TestLimit. But I detected problem when SQL Server tried to allocate more memory with disabled page file.
If I add pagefile it allows to use this amount of RAM + pagefile size.

So it looks like I can use only half of my RAM.
I tried Windows 7 x64 Ultimate, Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter, Windows 7 x64 Live CD.

I tried all possible combinations of these modules.
Any 2 modules works fine as 16 gb... but not all together..

Resource monitor shows 2nd 16Gb as free not as hardware reserved.

In addition Windows reports strange memory counters in each case:
1) If I use 2 modules it shows me used memory (in task manager): ~2.5 GB
2) if 4 is installed then task manager shows: ~5.5 GB

The same OS just rebooted in different hardware configuration eats different amount of RAM, something strange...

I wrote to Gigabyte Support, but there are not answer yet. I tried all of their BIOS.. nothing...

I also verified msconfig settings... not helps...

Comment: Can you explain what "this amount of RAM" means in "If I add pagefile it allows to use this amount of RAM + pagefile size."?

Comment: It is only RAM which can be allocated... available space. So I can address more than first ~16 gb if pagefile used, but I cannot get 2nd 16gb of physical memory.

Comment: So, even with an appropriately sized pagefile, you still can't use more than 16GB of RAM? Is that what you're saying?

Comment: 32 Gb installed RAM + 0 GB pagefile = ~16 Gb of allocatable memory... 32 gb + 16 gb of pagefile = ~32 Gb of allocatable memory...

Comment: That really doesn't answer my question. With an appropriately-sized pagefile, can you use all your RAM? If so, you don't actually have an issue.

Comment: no... I cannot use my RAM without pagefile or with pagefile.. I guessed that it is obvious that 32 Gb of RAM and 16GB of pagefile should allow to allocate 48 G in total...

Comment: So you've confirmed that even with a 16GB page file allocated, you still cannot get more than 16GB of physical memory to be used? It's surprisingly easy to test incorrectly. This is very specifically the thing you need to test -- otherwise you may not have any problem at all.

Comment: "physical memory" - no, I cannot use more 16 Gb, all above will be in swap file...

Comment: Can you post an image showing your system's memory usage taken while significant amounts of page file are in use? Preferably the Task Manager view that shows In Use, Available, Comitted, Cached, Paged Pool, and Non-paged pool.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43492/discussion-between-maxim-and-david-schwartz).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have reinstalled OS..
It is faster than delete all possible drivers. 
So I will install the same set of software and check which one causes described issue.

**UPDATE**

After fresh system installation I restored all my stack and tested after each package.
Now I am sure the reason is **MySQL x64** (v5.7.14).. it can be that other versions are also affected.

Total amount of locked memory is dependent on *innodb_buffer_pool_size*

This memory will not be visible in Task Manager and I think it is abnormal.

MariaDB 5.5 has the same issue!

Comment: This appears to be a comment rather than an answer to the question  you posed.

Comment: Maybe but it solved my question... :) I just have tested it now with TestLimit and all works. You can check our chat conversation with @David Schwartz